# Conflict between xwatermark and exam class

Tags: incompatibility, exam, xwatermark

I want to print a watermark in `exam` class in the following way as I don't want water mark in the foreground and with some opacity. As soon as I uncomment the `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}` it gives the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \lhead already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \chead already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \rhead already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \lfoot already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \cfoot already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \lfoot already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \rhead already defined.
```

Could someone please help me.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz[opacity=0.1]\node{Sankhya};}
%\newwatermark*[
%  allpages,
% angle=60,
%  scale=12,
%  xpos=-30,
%  ypos=15
%]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question This is my first Question.

\question This is my second question

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `xwatermark` loads `fancyhdr` and `exam.cls` defines precisely some of the commands which `fancyhdr` uses as well. Perhaps the `background` package is the better option here

Answer (score 4):

I fear `xwatermark` and `exam.cls` are really incompatible (unless a lot of redefinition occurs)

I switched to use the `background` package that can be used for watermarks etc. as well. Apply the `placement=` or `position=...` options to `\backgroundsetup` to shift the watermark.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz[opacity=0.4]\node{Sankhya};}

\backgroundsetup{angle=60,contents={\usebox\mybox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question This is my first Question.

\question This is my second question

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]